# Query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

So I have this DB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQD2Z.jpg

Every table has his ID which I use as PK's and FK's. What I need is to get the Product Family that haves more sales by State, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrEgl.png.

I'm doing something like this:

```
select 
    Sale_Details.state_id, 
    Producto_Family.family_id, 
    familia_producto.des_familia, 
    SUM(Sale_Details.amount) as Amount
```

And then I do the group by and joints starting from `Sale_Details` all the way through `Product_Family`, but I can't get it right because I'm getting some `Product_Family` twice in different States.

**I should get just one Product_Family per State, the one where it has more Sales of that Family, right?**

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, by the way.

Comment: Show your complete table structure with dummy data and your expected output.

Comment: @CrescentMoon thanks. What you need exactly, my query? Or the data of the table? I posted an example of the result in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  state, 
        PfamilyID,
        PFamilyName,
        Sales

FROM

    (   SELECT state.id as State,
        product_family.id as PfamilyID,
        product_family.name PFamilyName,
        SUM(saledetails.amount) Sales,
        row_number() over (partition by state.id order by SUM(saledetails.amount) desc) rownum

        FROM saledetails
        INNER JOIN sales ON saledetails.sales_id = sales.id
        INNER JOIN client ON sales.client_id=client.id
        INNER JOIN city ON client.city_id=city.id
        INNER JOIN state ON city.state_id=state.id
        INNER JOIN product ON saledetails.product_id=product.id
        INNER JOIN product_family ON product.product_family=product_family.id


        GROUP BY state.id,
        product_family.id,
        product_family.name ) X

WHERE rownum=1

GROUP BY    state,
            PfamilyID,
            PFamilyName,
            Sales
```

Answer (score 0):

This mostly likely will work based on group by State.  You can further consolidate this by either using a temp table of sorts, a subquery or even a CTE (where this is the actual CTE):

```
select
    State.Name
    ,City.Name
    ,Client.Name
    ,Product_Family.Name
    ,sum(Sales.Amount)
from
    State
inner join  
    City
on
    State.id = City.stateid
inner join
    Client
on
    City.id = Cient.CityId
inner join
    Sales
on
    Client.Id = Sales.ClientId
inner join
    Sale_Details    
on 
    Sales.Id = sales_Details.Sales_Id
inner join
    Product
on
    Sales_Details.Product_Id = Product.Id
inner join  
    Product_Family  
        on Product.Product_Family_id = Product_Family.Id

group by
    State.Name
    ,City.Name
    ,Client.Name
    ,Product_Family.Name
order by 
    State.Name
    ,City.Name
    ,Client.Name
    ,Product_Family.Name
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it gave me the same result. It shows me all the sales per State that every Family Product has, so it shows me the State more than one time, but I just need the one that has more sale, so it should show the State just one time, with that Family that has the bigger sales. 

I need is something like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5595251/example3.png but when I add the other tables, it shows me the State more than one time.

I don't know if I'm explaining myself right. Here's the results of your query: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5595251/example2.png

Comment: And you are saying that if you remove the City.Name, Client.Name and Product_Family.Name from the selection and group that you don't get the values you seek, i.e. it is duplicated somewhere?

Comment: There is no City name, just State ID. If I select the State ID and the  MAX(amount) I get it right. No duplicated States. But if I include the  Family Product Code and Name, which I need them because I need to know the Family Product that has more sales in each State, then I get the States more than one time, because it shows the Amounts for every Family Product in each State.

Comment: Are you trying to just get the most popular family product code in each state (with totals)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You will need to do a query using:  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State,Product_family ORDER BY sum() where row_Number() = 1